# How to check if @everyone can send messages in specific Discord channel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Basically, I need a function that returns `true` or `false` depending on whether a specified channel has the `SEND_MESSAGES` permission for @everyone checked. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to get both the `Role` and the `Channel` object to check the permission for the role in that particular channel. And then you check the permissions in that particular channel has a particular permission or not.

Eg: **Checking with the role object**:

```
let role = message.guild.roles.cache.get('roleid');
let channel = message.guild.channels.cache.get('channelid');
if(role.permissionsIn(channel).has('Permissions.FLAGS')){
    //do your thing.
}
```

Eg: **Checking with the channel object**:

```
let role = message.guild.roles.cache.get('roleid');
let channel = message.guild.channels.cache.get('channelid');
if(channel.permissionsFor(role).has('Permissions.FLAGS')){
    //do your thing.
}
```

**Note**: The `everyone` role ID is same as the guild ID. So use the guild ID to get the `everyone` role object.

Reference: [`permissionsFor()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=permissionsFor), [`permissionsIn()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=permissionsIn), [`Permissions.FLAGS`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Permissions?scrollTo=s-FLAGS).

Comment: You could also just use [`Role#permissions#has()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=permissions) if you want to check the overall guild permissions

Comment: Whoops, I didn't read the whole question. My apologies